# What's the correct usage of withEscapeChar in open CSV

Tags: java, opencsv

Using this codes as an example of what i'm seeing, I set the escape character to `'&'` but it just doesn't seem to escape the separator. I expect to get an array of 3 items from this code because I am escaping the comma between dog and monkey, but I'm getting 4. Am I using this correctly, because I can't believe it simply doesn't work?

The javadoc says "Sets the character to use for escaping a separator or quote." so I expect this to escape the separator.

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.StringReader;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    import com.opencsv.CSVParserBuilder;
    import com.opencsv.CSVReaderBuilder;

    public class EscapeTest {
        public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {

        new CSVReaderBuilder(new StringReader("fish,cat,dog&,monkey"))
            .withCSVParser(new CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator(',').withEscapeChar('&').build()).build().readAll()
            .forEach(item -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(item)));
        ;

        }

    }
```

Note the output for this gives:

```
[fish, cat, dog, monkey]
```

So it has detected my escape character and removed it from my string, but it's still gone ahead and treated the comma as a separator.

Comment: Relates to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/205505/38735

Comment: Why do you expect to get an array of 3 items?

Comment: Because the comma between dog and monkey is escaped by the escape character.

Comment: `.withEscapeChar('\\\\')`

Comment: @JudeNiroshan that code doesn't even compile because it's 2 characters, and I can't see why this would work anyway?